# How do I increase a value (num) in a method and decrease another defined in a class in Python?

Tags: python

I am making a game in python and I need to create a method to increase/decrease a value that I define in a class. The method receives a number and with that i have to modify the other. This is my code:

```
class Ant:
    def __init__(self, name, steps, health, alcohol, state):
        self.name = name
        self.steps = []
        self.health = 100
        self.alcohol = 0
        self.state = state
```

I need to modify the health.. Help me please

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: Do you know how to write a method? Do you know how to modify a number?

Answer (score 2):

Define a method with a single argument and modify the `self.health`:

```
class Ant:
    def __init__(self, name, steps, health, alcohol, state):
        self.name = name
        self.steps = []
        self.health = 100
        self.alcohol = 0
        self.state = state

    def add_health(self, value):
        self.health += value

    # bonus
    def drink(self, value):
        self.alcohol += value
        self.health -= value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make some function that subtracts from the `Ant`s health. For example:

```
class Ant:
    def __init__(self, name, steps, health, alcohol, state):
        self.name = name
        self.steps = []
        self.health = 100
        self.alcohol = 0
        self.state = state

    def damage(self, amount):
        self.health -= amount
```